# Wordpress Custom Comments

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have a client site that has requested a custom comment format for posts of a specific category.

In my loop template, I have this:

```
<div id="gallery-commentlist">
     <ul class="gallery-commentlist">
          <?php wp_list_comments( 'type=comment&callback=gallery_comment'); ?>
     </ul>
</div><!-- #gallery-commentlist -->
```

And in my functions.php file, I have this:

```
<?php function gallery_comment($comment, $args, $depth) {
   $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>
   <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
     <div id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="gallery-comment-body">
            <p><span class="gallery-comment-author"><?php comment_text() ?>:</span> <?php comment_text() ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ) ?>"> &ndash; 
        <?php get_comment_date() ?> at <?php get_comment_time() ?></a><?php edit_comment_link(__('(Edit)'),'  ','') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php }?>
```

It's not returning any comments, and for the life of me, I can't figure out why. I followed the instructions in the WP codex to the letter. Is there something that I have overlooked?

Thanks for any help!

ty

Comment: Even some Wordpress cracks lurk here, this is more a programming site. Consider to [ask wordpress support requests on the wordpress forums](http://wordpress.org/support/forum/how-to-and-troubleshooting).

Comment: I know. I posted it here in case the issue was my PHP code.

Comment: Looks more that as you use a callback here, wordpress is passed by so functions like `comment_class()` and stuff does not work. I suspect that setting a single global variable is not doing enough. But that's just a guess, hopefully helpful.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments

Comment: Use php echo statements to see how far your code works and debug from there. Then make sure your Discussion settings in Wordpress > Dashboard > Settings allow you to display the posts.

Comment: Comments are all approved, and everything on the page works, including the custom comments entry form. The only thing that is nonresponsive is the function call. My next step is to put all of the function code directly in the template and go from there.

Comment: @hakre Are you aware of [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Richard: Sure, it is for [Wordpress Developers and Administrators](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq) and I'd say Ty Morton ain't one so I suggest the in my eyes better option of the superb wordpress.org support forums.

Comment: @hakre There's no need to be rude. These sites are for asking questions, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is apparently some sort of query call that takes place as part of the `comments_template()` call, just as there is with loop calls.

When I put my custom function in the comments template, it works perfectly.

I tried putting the contents of the comments template into my custom loop-single template, and it didn't work.

The solution wound up being placing an if{} statement in the comments template, and then setting up two different layouts based upon the results.

Now it all works like it should.